# How do i make my search bar actually search pages in my site?

Tags: html, search-box

I put a search bar into my website but I don't know how to make it actually search pages within my site. I don't want a google search bar where you can search anything. I already have the search bar in my site, but nothing happens when you press search. Help is much appreciated.

here is the html to my search bar:

```
<div class="search">
    <form class="form-wrapper-2 cf">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search Yacht..." required>
        <button type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: The way you would implement something like this would depend on the language you are using to build your pages. I suggest reading about database management and querying, just to start, before attempting to build a custom search engine. After you actually attempt to build something more than a couple of HTML lines, we can offer some help.

Comment: Either you install and manage your own search engine (ElasticSearch, OpenSearch and Meilisearch), or you use a managed one (Algolia, Google Programmable Search Engine and Lixia Search). Or, also, you can build your own, but I don't recommend this approach.

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat straight forward suggestion if you don't want some type of Google Searchbar would be to run a script on submission of the form that searches the text in each of the web pages in your working directory to find a match, then display a page with links to the found matches.

I will use PHP for my description of how this is done.

With this in mind, first learn how to read entire pages (i.e. webpages) into a string:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

```
//YOU WILL HAVE TO LINE THIS UP WITH YOUR WORKING FILE NAMES
$home = file_get_contents('./home.php', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
```

or I suppose you could just search for the actual webpage/URL like so:

```
$home = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');//IMAGINE THIS IS REALLY HOME.PHP
$homePageName = "home.php";//JUST HERE TO SHOW AN EXAMPLE
```

Example:

```
///YOUR FORM/INPUT BOX
<form action="search.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="findMe" placeholder="Search Yacht">
</form>
```

Now search.php

```
$search = $_POST['findMe'];
//$search = "example";//THIS WOULD WORK, BUT I WAS SHOWING HOW TO USE FORM

//IF WORD FOUND IN HOME PAGE
if (stripos($home, $search) !== false) {//USING EXAMPLE.COM TO SHOW IT WORKS
    echo '<a href="'.$homePageName.'">'.$homePageName.'</a>';
}
```

Then if you want to be simplistic and not use an array to store the found pages, take the same code above and use it for every page you want searched (i.e. home, about, products, etc..).

Now a user can search your site (or the pages you want indexed), to find all pages that have matching text. If you want specific keywords to be searched, just add them to the page metadata and the process I have described will still work as it searches everything that makes up the page.

```
<meta name="keywords" content="keyword1, keyword2, keyword3 " />
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the sample HTML form code for search bar:

```
<form id="sarchform" class="search2" method="get" action="source.html" />
<input class="search2" id="test" type="text" name="search" size="10" maxlength="255"/>
```

Here's the JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('searchform').onsubmit = function() {
    window.location = 'http://www.google.com/search?q=site:yourdomainname ' + document.getElementById('test').value;
    return false;
}
</script>
```

Mention your domain name in the code above and try implementing this.

Comment: how to put this in an external js file?